80s horror movie - Teenagers in mansion are attacked by deformed man\monster
I have been trying so hard to find the title of the 80s movie where a group of teenagers enters a mansion for a sort of experiment. The mansion is full of secret passages and they need to stay overnight or for several days (not sure). They have been chased by a man-looking monster.
The movie is full of hide and seek scenes and is very tense. Eventually they managed to kill it outside the mansion stabbing it on the garden fence. 
The monster was actually a terrifying looking man that was born in such shape as he spent over 12 months in his mother's womb. This is what I can recall. 

Sounds like the cult horror film Hell Night from 1981 with Linda Blair.

Before being able to join Alpha Sigma Rho fraternity and its sister sorority, four pledges must spend the night in Garth Manor, twelve years to the day after the previous resident murdered his entire family. Some, however, say that one member of the Garth family survived, and still resides somewhere in the now-deserted mansion.

The mansion is full of secret passages, the main killer (Andrew Garth) is deformed because he stayed 10 and a half months in his mother's womb and in the end he's impaled on a gate. Here's the trailer:



